# Woocommerce additional registration / profile information

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to setup a site that would have a simple registration. Basically I want to collect user name (user name would be clients email address) and password only, for the initial registration. After the account is setup, I'd like to collect additional demographic information. I would either like to detect first login, or detect if the information has been submitted, if not I would like to display a reminder every time the user logs in until the user submits data. What would be the best way to accomplish this? Is there a Woocommerce hook or Wordpress hook that would accomplish this?

Thank you in advance!!
-MK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would accomplish this by creating an extra column in the database called 'completed' when the user initially signs up with their username and password, set it to false and do an sql statement followed by an if statement to check if the field for that user says false, if it does then prompt them to enter more details, when they enter the details, change it to say true and when it does say true then don't prompt them again

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'tableName' WHERE 'idRow' = '".$_SESSION['']."' LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($sql);

if($row['complete'] == false) {
     //prompt some stuff here
} else {
     //carry on 
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a good solution. Would you tie that in with the Wordpress user meta? How would you tie that together with the user profile?

Comment: I've never personally used Wordpress, I prefer to hard code everything and I guess that when the user signs in you could store their userID in a session variable and you'd match it against the session, I'll edit my answer with a little snippet of what the code would look like